# C# user control interact with control on parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have a web form where I have a Label and a user control.
I would like that the user control would be able to change the value of the text in the Label.

How can I indicate to the user control what Label to change?
(In the example I have a single Label a a single instance of the user control, but I will need to have several of both)

EDIT:The user interaction with the user control triggers the update of the external label.

EDIT2: Adding more details.
My user control has a gridview, when the user adds or edit a line to the grid, I want to update the value in the label with the sum over a column of the grid.
Currently I'm using the code server side, as the request to update or insert goes to the server.
If possible, I prefer to do the update on the client side, as that would allow me to update my label without having to reload the whole page.

Solution: changed to use devexpress components, I use the aspxgridview client side event EndCallback in the user object. I defined a property in my user object to store the javascript function to be called in the EndCallback callback.
This Property can be filled by the container page, as there I know all the IDs I need.

The code I have is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <uc1:InvoiceItems runat="server" ID="InvoiceItems" />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the changes in the client side.
I in my user object I did:

```
public String ClientCallback { get; set; }
private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      GridView.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = ClientCallback;
    }
```

On the page I have:

```
<dr:UserObject runat="server" ID="UserObject1"
ClientCallback="UpdateFeesTotal" />
```

The function UpdateFeesTotal is a javascript function that updates the Labels, Now also using a ASPxLabel to use the client side functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which label you want to control, you can always have some property in user control, which keeps that label id.

Comment: I tried this method, but how can I get the Control itself? I tried to use `this.FindControl(LabelID)` or `this.Parent.FindControl(LabelID)` but I'm always getting null as result. LabelId is a string with the ID of my label, and it is correctly filled.

Comment: Can you give a little more feedback about what are you trying to do, especially if you are trying to do this on client side, or you need this on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a generic method in your control to set values of a label and pass that label control to the function.

The function simply does passedLabel.Text = "My Text"